# Element 'footer' cannot be nested witin element 'html'

Tags: html

Pretty simple question. Why does this error occur, and how do i correct it?

running visual studio express 2012 for web.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add the problematic code. Also the error message is quite clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<footer>` tag should be within the `<body>` tag

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, it did the job !

i was wondering, why is my post getting voted down?

Comment: @Avacay The reason you were getting downvoted was because your question is very vague without any code snippets or examples of the code you have, which would help people understand what you're asking and improve the general quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incredibly vague but I can tell you what you're doing wrong.

You probably have your `<footer>`tag outside of your `<body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

    <footer>
    </footer>

</html>
```

So you probably have something that looks similar to that, however it should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```